# Reversing a while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, decimal

Reversing a while loop, I don't know if it's the correct way to ask the question, but come on. I have a code that converts any whole number to a two or three digit decimal. How?
dividing the integer value by two until it is less than 10, counting in turn the times it divided it in the redo variable, thus we obtain the tenth: `decimal = (integer, redo):`

```
        int InitialInteger = 190;
        int Integer = InitialInteger;
        int redo = 0;
        while (Integer > 10)
        {
            Integer = Integer / 2;
            redo++;
        }
        //Salida: 5,5
```

Now I want to get back the initial integer value ("reverse the loop") that is, multiply the integer part by 2 as many times as the decimal part indicates: `Integer = (decimal1 * 2)^decimal2`

```
        int decimal1 = Int16.Parse(Decimal.Split(',')[0]);
        int decimal2 = Int16.Parse(Decimal.Split(',')[1]);
        while (decimal2 > 0)
        {
            redo -= 1;
            InitialInteger += decimal2 * 2;
        }
        //Salida: 60
```

but it doesn't work, it never returns the initial value!
Any idea?

Comment: `190/2=95`,  `95/2=47.5`  but you store the result in an integer, so `47` is stored. That why you will never get back to the original `190` is you reverse your loop...

Comment: To reverse it you'd do `Integer * Math.Pow(2, redo)`, or a loop like `while(redo > 0) {Integer = Integer * 2; redo--;}` but as @Luuk mentioned your algorithm is not reversible for any numbers that are not divisible by a single digit number and a power of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have to set Integer as a float instead of as int for it to work.

Use this instead

```cs
int InitialInteger = 190;
float temp = InitialInteger;
int redo = 0;
while (temp > 10)
{
    temp= temp / 2;
    redo++;
}
```

and then to reverse

```cs
while (redo > 0)
{
    temp = temp * 2;
    redo--;
}
```

At the end temp (or Integer as you called it!) is again 190